# AWS Route 53 pricing for hosted zones and domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ecs

Novice dealing with DNS services here. I'm setting up an ECS cluster of Fargate containers that need to communicate with each other. They are deployed as separate services in the same cluster, so I wanted to use CloudMap in order to automatically tie domain names to their ip addresses.

These names needed only be reachable from inside the VPC itself, so I did not want to register a public domain name. As such, I created a private hosted zone, ECS successfully registered my containers and testing confirmed that they reachable by name from inside the VPC.

What I don't understand yet is how billing works for this. According to the route 53 [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/?nc1=h_ls), a private hosted zone in us-east-1 costs $0.5/month for the first 25 zones. There's also a cost of $0.4 per million queries/first 1 billion DNS queries per month.

So far so good, but there is a section about domain name pricing. They link to this [document](https://d32ze2gidvkk54.cloudfront.net/Amazon_Route_53_Domain_Registration_Pricing_20140731.pdf) that lists the price per TLD, but I take it this refers to publicly accessible domain names registered with authoritative namespace servers, and does not apply to the domain name I gave my private hosted zone? So I wouldn't get charged for this?

And how would those domain names work with public hosted zones? From what I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648997/understand-public-hosted-zone-aws-route53), the domain names we give our public hosted zones do not get automatically registered with the root NS servers, so the domain name charges would not apply. To get our domain names registered, we'd need to manually purchase the domain through [a process like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-register.html) and then we would get charged. Would that be correct?

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're thinking about this too much, it's fairly simple.

Hosted zones cost $0.50 per zone, then per-request pricing. Domain name pricing is optional and independent. Add the cost of the services you use together, that's the price.

In your case I would think you would use hosted zones but no domain registration. You can make subdomains of a corporate domain in Route53 if you want to, no need to delegate from your public zones if they don't need to be publicly accessible.